# error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QJson/Parser': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt, qjson

I am getting this error when i am trying to run my Qt project downloaded from this link 
https://code.google.com/p/qml-google-maps/downloads/list

I'm trying to compile it in `Qt 5.0.2`.

```
error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QJson/Parser': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you using qjson, and not the json parser in Qt 5? Why? I have just cloned the project with `git clone https://code.google.com/p/qml-google-maps/`, but I cannot find such entries. Please clarify why I cannot see those. Where do they come from?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are getting this when running? Include error is usually compilation time error, not run time unless it is some interpreted language, whereas this seems to be C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clone and build qjson library from here
https://github.com/flavio/qjson